# Why for 7 | 5m+2n you can just make 7 | 5n+2n - 7n

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Why for 7 | 5m+2n you can just make 7 | 5n+2n - 7n
Why can you just add te 7n, and is it only true for whole numbers = n.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: $5n + 2n - 7n = 0$ (? you meant $5m + 2n - 7n$?

Comment: Hint: $\,a\,$ and $\,a-7n\,$  have the same remainder when divided by $7$. In particular: one of them is divisible by $7$ iff the other is (special case when the remainder $=0)\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Since $7\mid 5m+2n$, we can write $5m+2n=7k$ for some $k$.  Then 
$$
5m+2n-7n=7k-7n=7(k-n)
$$
which shows that $7\mid 5m+2n-7n$.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing used in long division. You can use known multiples of your divisor, and not change the remainder  on division by that divisor, at the end of the long division sequence.